# Somar colunas mysql

Tags: mysql

Boa tarde, abri uma pergunta ontem porem não consegui me expressar de maneira correta, tenho a seguinte query

`SELECT C.id, C.name as NomePC, C.serial AS Serial, MF.name AS Fabricante, CM.name AS ModeloPC,OS.name AS Sistema, OSV.name AS OSVersao,DP.designation AS Processador, IDH.capacity AS CapacidadeHD, DH.designation AS ModeloHD, DGC.designation AS PlacaVideo, IDM.size AS Memoria, DM.designation AS tipoMemoria
    FROM glpi_computers AS C
    INNER JOIN glpi_manufacturers AS MF ON C.manufacturers_id = MF.id
    INNER JOIN glpi_computermodels as CM ON C.computermodels_id = CM.id
    INNER JOIN glpi_operatingsystems AS OS ON C.operatingsystems_id = OS.id
    INNER JOIN glpi_operatingsystemversions AS OSV ON C.operatingsystemversions_id = OSV.id
    INNER JOIN glpi_items_deviceprocessors AS IDP ON C.id = IDP.items_id
    INNER JOIN glpi_deviceprocessors AS DP on IDP.deviceprocessors_id = DP.id 
    INNER JOIN glpi_items_deviceharddrives AS IDH on C.id = IDH.items_id
    INNER JOIN glpi_deviceharddrives AS DH on IDH.deviceharddrives_id = DH.id
    INNER JOIN glpi_items_devicegraphiccards AS IDGC on C.id = IDGC.items_id 
    INNER JOIN glpi_devicegraphiccards AS DGC ON IDGC.devicegraphiccards_id = DGC.id
    INNER JOIN glpi_items_devicememories AS IDM on C.id = IDM.items_id
    INNER JOIN glpi_devicememories AS DM on IDM.devicememories_id = DM.id
    WHERE C.id = 271 AND IDH.capacity != 0`

e estou obtendo o seguinte resultado

[image: query atual]

quando o PC tem mais de um pente de memoria ram eu obtenho 2 resultados da query como mostra na imagem, eu preciso obter apenas UM resultado porem SOMANDO a quantidade de memória como na imagem abaixo (tive que apagar a imagem por não ter reputação suficiente para postar 3 imagens)

como posso fazer isso pelo proprio mysql?

## RESOLVIDO

Agora tenho outro problema, tentei replicar a solução (usar SUM) no HD, porem ele ta dobrando o tamanho do meu hd, ele tem apenas 500gb e como resultado da query estou obtendo o dobro
[image: hd]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta você utilizar a função `SUM(coluna)` na coluna da memória, e agrupar pelas outras que serão iguais, pelo `Group By`

Segue código:

```
SELECT 
C.id, 
C.name as NomePC, 
C.serial AS Serial, 
MF.name AS Fabricante,
 CM.name AS ModeloPC,
OS.name AS Sistema, 
OSV.name AS OSVersao,
DP.designation AS Processador, 
IDH.capacity AS CapacidadeHD, 
DH.designation AS ModeloHD, 
DGC.designation AS PlacaVideo, 
SUM(IDM.size) AS Memoria, 
DM.designation AS tipoMemoria
    FROM glpi_computers AS C
    INNER JOIN glpi_manufacturers AS MF ON C.manufacturers_id = MF.id
    INNER JOIN glpi_computermodels as CM ON C.computermodels_id = CM.id
    INNER JOIN glpi_operatingsystems AS OS ON C.operatingsystems_id = OS.id
    INNER JOIN glpi_operatingsystemversions AS OSV ON C.operatingsystemversions_id = OSV.id
    INNER JOIN glpi_items_deviceprocessors AS IDP ON C.id = IDP.items_id
    INNER JOIN glpi_deviceprocessors AS DP on IDP.deviceprocessors_id = DP.id 
    INNER JOIN glpi_items_deviceharddrives AS IDH on C.id = IDH.items_id
    INNER JOIN glpi_deviceharddrives AS DH on IDH.deviceharddrives_id = DH.id
    INNER JOIN glpi_items_devicegraphiccards AS IDGC on C.id = IDGC.items_id 
    INNER JOIN glpi_devicegraphiccards AS DGC ON IDGC.devicegraphiccards_id = DGC.id
    INNER JOIN glpi_items_devicememories AS IDM on C.id = IDM.items_id
    INNER JOIN glpi_devicememories AS DM on IDM.devicememories_id = DM.id
    WHERE C.id = 271 AND IDH.capacity != 0

    GROUP BY C.id, C.name, C.serial ,  MF.name, CM.name ,  OS.name , 
OSV.name ,  DP.designation ,   IDH.capacity ,  DH.designation , 
DGC.designation ,  DM.designation
```

**Edit:**

Para somar, tamanho do hd, e quantidade de memória, sem agrupar pelas outras colunas:

```
SELECT 
C.id, 
C.name as NomePC, 
C.serial AS Serial, 
MF.name AS Fabricante,
 CM.name AS ModeloPC,
OS.name AS Sistema, 
OSV.name AS OSVersao,
DP.designation AS Processador, 
(Select Sum(IDH.capacity) from glpi_items_deviceharddrives AS IDH where IDH.items_id = C.id) AS CapacidadeHD, 
DGC.designation AS PlacaVideo, 
(Select  SUM(IDM.size) from glpi_items_devicememories AS IDM where IDM.items_id = C.id) AS Memoria
    FROM glpi_computers AS C
    INNER JOIN glpi_manufacturers AS MF ON C.manufacturers_id = MF.id
    INNER JOIN glpi_computermodels as CM ON C.computermodels_id = CM.id
    INNER JOIN glpi_operatingsystems AS OS ON C.operatingsystems_id = OS.id
    INNER JOIN glpi_operatingsystemversions AS OSV ON C.operatingsystemversions_id = OSV.id
    INNER JOIN glpi_items_deviceprocessors AS IDP ON C.id = IDP.items_id
    INNER JOIN glpi_deviceprocessors AS DP on IDP.deviceprocessors_id = DP.id 
    INNER JOIN glpi_items_devicegraphiccards AS IDGC on C.id = IDGC.items_id 
    INNER JOIN glpi_devicegraphiccards AS DGC ON IDGC.devicegraphiccards_id = DGC.id
    WHERE C.id = 271 and (Select Sum(IDH.capacity) from glpi_items_deviceharddrives AS IDH where IDH.items_id = C.id) > 0
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62983/discussion-on-answer-by-rovann-linhalis-somar-colunas-mysql)